# Script to create a four character string based on known numerical relationships

Tags: bash, shell

Consider a three line input file containing four unique numbers (1,2,3,4) such that each line represents the position of one number relative to another number.

So for example in the following input set, 4 is next to 2, 2 is next to 3, and 1 is next to 4.

```
42
23
14
```

So given that how would a script assemble all four numbers in such a way that it maintains each numbers known relationship?

In other words there are two answers 1423 or 3241 but how to arrive at that programmatically?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: I updated the question. The expected output is 1423 and/or 3241.

Comment: I think this is slanted towards Stack overflow. One answer could just output the “right” answers and be done with it, but if you’re looking for programmatic solutions, I think you should ask on SO.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Nah, this is a job for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute forcing the luck:

```
for (( ; ; ))
do
  res=($(echo "42
    23
    14" | shuf))     
  if ((${res[0]}%10 == ${res[1]}/10 && ${res[1]}%10 == ${res[2]}/10))
  then
      echo "success: ${res[@]}"
      break 
  fi
  echo "fail: ${res[@]}"
done

fail: 42 14 23
fail: 42 23 14
fail: 42 14 23
success: 14 42 23
```

For 3 numbers, this approach is acceptable.

Shuf shuffles the input lines and fills the array res with the numbers.

Then we take to following numbers and test, if the last digit of the first matches the first digit of the next, and for the 2nd and 3rd number accordingly.

If so, we break with a success message. For debugging, a failure message is better than a silent endless loop.

For longer chains of numbers, a systematic permutation might be better to test and a function to check two following numbers, which can be called by index or better a loop would be suitable.

Comment: `for (( ; ; ))` ;)

Comment: This works perfectly for my needs. I was easily able to modify it to work with my goal of up to 7 digits. Thank you so much!

Comment: @S.Haran: The canonical way to thank for helpful posts is, to click on the elements on the left. :) This allows the system to decide, whether the post is listed under unsolved or solved questions.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sensible or efficient, but fun (for me, at least) :-)

This will echo all the permutations using **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel echo {1}{2}{3}{4} ::: {1..4} ::: {1..4} ::: {1..4} ::: {1..4}
```

And add some `grepping` on the end:

```
parallel echo {1}{2}{3}{4} ::: {1..4} ::: {1..4} ::: {1..4} ::: {1..4} | grep -E "42|24" | grep -E "23|32" | grep -E "14|41"
```

**Output**

```
1423
3241
```